# Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I asked this question before too. Maybe someone can caught the error here.

```
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var dish={
        name:'Uthapizza',
        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
        category: 'mains', 
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
                rating:5,
                comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                author:"John Lemon",
                date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
                rating:2,
                comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                author:"25 Cent",
                date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
    };
    $scope.dish = dish;
}])
.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.newcomment = {
        rating : "",
        comment: "",
        author: "",
        date: new Date().toISOString()
    };
    $scope.submitComment = function () {
        $scope.newcomment.date = new Date().toISOString();
        $scope.newcomment.rating = parseInt($scope.newcomment.rating)
        console.log($scope.newcomment.comment);
        console.log($scope.newcomment.author);
        console.log($scope.newcomment.rating);
        console.log($scope.newcomment.date);
        $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.newcomment);
    }
}]);
```

In html part part I have only two-three textbox. `SubmitComment` in button onclick. Console.log show me the result which I need. But I cannot push this to array. The exercise is a part of tutorial. So it was requirement to write them in seperate controllers and this was provided by the tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: @Craicerjack. Yes I have tried as that example, too. But  nothing

Answer (score 0):

The dish object is not defined in the second controller which make sense from the error "undefined".
You have to find a way to pass the dish object from the first controller "DishDetailController" to the second one "DishCommentController".
There are several ways to do it, one way is to stock the object into service from the first controller then retrieve it from the same service in the second controller. As I know the best way to share objects between controlllers is via services.

Comment: Thanks for response I even newcomment part into the first Controller. I can access that from the second controller, too. But problem is that I still cannot push this to array. whatever I am doing I cannot push this to anohter one